# Owl-carousel - TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: jquery, reactjs, create-react-app, owl-carousel

I tried to use owl.carousel package in my react app.
I installed jquery and owl.carousel package with npm.

```
npm install jquery owl.carousel
```

In App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'owl.carousel';


componentDidMount() {
$('.team-slides').owlCarousel({
// my options
});
}
```

I got error message

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined.
/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js:1718

  1715 |  * @todo Navigation plugin `next` and `prev`
  1716 |  * @public
  1717 |  */
> 1718 | $.fn.owlCarousel = function(option) {
       | ^  1719 |  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  1720 | 
  1721 |    return this.each(function() {
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to include these in your `index.html`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but what if you already have installed jquery? why are you referencing from the CDN?

Comment: it looks like what you need is actually the slim version not the regular one to get owl carousel to work.

Comment: jquery had to be loaded first before loading the owl libraries.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

This one is enough try this script I hope your carousel will work properly..